# SmartGWT DateChooser disable specific dates

Tags: smartgwt

I need to disable (or make them for example red) specific dates in SmartGWT DateChooser. I was trying to use setDisabledDates(Date... disabledDates) and change cssStyle using setDisabledWeeenddayStyle, but it takes no effect. Any ideas how can I do that?

```
public class CustomDateItem extends DateItem {

    private DateChooser chooser = new DateChooser();

    public CustomDateItem() {
        this("", "");
    }

    public CustomDateItem(String name, String title) {
        super(name, title);
        onInit();
    }

    private void onInit() {
        Date date = new Date(2014, 06, 27);
        chooser.setDisabledDates(date);
        setPickerProperties(chooser);
    }
}
```

This is my DateItem.java. However, if i try something like this:

```
public class CustomDateItem extends DateItem {

    public CustomDateItem() {
        this("", "");
    }

    public CustomDateItem(String name, String title) {
        super(name, title);
        onInit();
    }

    private void onInit() {
        Date date = new Date(2014, 06, 27);
        System.out.println(date);
        getPickerProperties().setDisabledDates(date);
    }
}
```

i got js error:

```
com.google.gwt.core.client.JavaScriptException: (TypeError) @com.smartgwt.client.util.JSOHelper::setAttribute(Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;Ljava/lang/String;Lcom/google/gwt/core/client/JavaScriptObject;)([null, string: 'disabledDates', JavaScript object(341)]): elem is null
```

but as you can see, "date" is not null and getPickerProperties() creates its own DateChooser.

Comment: can you show the code you have written ?

Comment: updates main question.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, resolved. Dates has to be declarated just like this:

```
Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 05, 26);
```

and all code should look like this:

```
public class DateItem extends com.smartgwt.client.widgets.form.fields.DateItem {

    private DateChooser chooser = new DateChooser();

    public DateItem(String name, String title) {
        super(name, title);
        onInit();
    }

    private void onInit() {
        Calendar cal1 = new GregorianCalendar(2014, 05, 26);
        Date[] dates = new Date[]{cal1.getTime()};
        chooser.setDisabledDates(dates);
        chooser.setDisabledWeekdayStyle("holidays");
        chooser.setDisabledWeekendStyle("holidays");
        setPickerProperties(chooser);
    }
}
```

Hope it will help someone.